# Project rejected from bitbucket

Tags: git, android-studio, github, jetbrains-ide

After create a project in bitbucket, I'm trying to push my done application.

1. VCS - Enable version control
2. right click on app in left panel and GIT add
3. commit and push ( from ctrl+shift+k )
4. android studio give me windows with input for user and url, after put them, I got atlassian windows for password and username
5. and finally i got **PUSH REJECTED - push to origin/master was rejected** and nothing more ...

Now I don't know what is wrong and what I should do

What I should do now ?